# how to open a folder that opens in the middle of the screen and at a certain size

Tags: c#, windows, resize, directory

This code opens a folder if the "TotalFileCount" == 0. I want to open the folder and have it centered on the screen and I want it to be a specific size. Is there a way to do that in C#?

```
if (TotalFileCount == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("There are no files in this directory. Please add pictures to this folder: " + AppVars.PolicyImagesDirectory + " and try again.", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    btnBrowse.Focus();

    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = AppVars.PolicyImagesDirectory;
    process.Start(); 
 }
```

When the new Windows Explorer window opens, can I make it a specific size and center it on the screen?

Comment: So your question is "When the new Windows Explorer window is opened, can I make it a certain size and put it in a certain position?"

Comment: yes, when you double click on a folder for example, it opens the explorer. i want to resize that view.

Comment: Really, I do not want an application to resize my other application's windows.

Comment: This sounds like a job for the ExplorerBrowser control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the handle from the process then call the native SetWindowPos from the win32 api

```
process.handle //to get the handle of the window.

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int W, int H, uint uFlags);
```

Comment: `Process.handle` is the **process** handle, not the **window** handle that you need for `SetWindowPos`. Not downvoting, because `SetWindowPos` is probably the right choice, but you need to fix to be correct; the first line is totally wrong.